# In ant, how to copy only typical extension file excluding other

Tags: ant, build

how to copy only particular file from directory having mix of extension files. For example my directory is having .jar, .exe , .xml, .deb and I just want to copy .deb from that directory excluding all other using ant command. Any way to do that? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<copy todir="somedir">
  <fileset>
    <fileset dir="someotherdir" includes="*.deb"/>
  </fileset>
</copy>
```